# Microsoft adds tracking purcahse value in wwocommoerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ads, tracking

I am trying to install tracking for microsoft adds, I have managed to tracks number of orders recieved from microsoft adds but not the order value.

This is the code that needs editing, as you can see i need to replace the 'revenue_value' in the code with the function from my checkout page but not sure what to put.

```
<script>
   window.uetq = window.uetq || [];  
   window.uetq.push('event', '', {'revenue_value': Replace_with_Variable_Revenue_Function(), 'currency': 'Replace_with_Currency_Code'});    
</script>

   ...

 // Here is an example function, named "GetRevenueValue()", that defines variable revenue:

<script>
   function GetRevenueValue()
      { return 6; }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your exact error you need help resolving? Or you expect us to just write it out for you? Provide more info on what exactly is expected, how to replicate, and what you have tried exactly..

Comment: I am trying to track the value of orders coming from microsoft adds, the code in my question is the example code found at https://help.ads.microsoft.com/#apex/ads/en/56687/2-500 but this line needs editing {'revenue_value': Replace_with_Variable_Revenue_Function(), the 'revenue_value' needs replacing so it can find the value on my checkout page

Comment: In your comment you did not add ANY new information, nor you mentioned what I asked..  For me this question is not in the guidelines of [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and as such it should be closed!